# MSTest - unit test with StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, mstest

I wrote program in `C#` that invokes `MSTest` from command line.
One of test cases throws `StackOverflowException` and it causes, that `QtAgent32` (and my application) process breaks.
What can I do to prevent from this situation (I can't change unit tests)?

Comment: Can you share your c# code? Ideally same dialog box should appear from the c# code as well and am wondering whether it has something to do with process startInfo parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way by which you can avoid these kind of crashes is by setting the legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy property in QTAgent32.exe.config (and/or QTAgent.exe.config depending upon the bitness of the machine/testrun) as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx). Relevant text from this link is: -

*As a temporary compatibility measure, administrators can place a compatibility flag in the  section of the application configuration file. This causes the common language runtime to revert to the behavior of versions 1.0 and 1.1.*

This will switch the "unhandled exception" handling behaviour to .net 1.1 and the process will not crash on such exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot catch `StackOverflowException` on .NET (starting with the 2.0 version). This probably means that there is no way to solve the problem you have - because the unit testing framework simply cannot catch the exception.

See the following related SO question:

- [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception).

There are some interesting suggestions on the other thread - for example, you can create `Thread` and check the current `FrameCount` to detect the stack overflow earlier. However, that probably won't be very reliable. So, I'm afraid there is no good answer...

Comment: OK, but when I invoke MSTest from command line (not from C# code), when this unit test is executing I can just click cancel on error message box and MSTest continue to run. I don't know how to do something like this but in C# code

Comment: @mirt -- can you add that extra information into the original question? Those are good details.