# What design decisions led to StackOverflowException being uncatchable in .NET 2.0+?

Tags: .net, clr, stack-overflow

As far as I can tell, there is no fundamental reason why `StackOverflowException` should be uncatchable. And yet it is.

A thread's stack has a maximum size which defaults to 1MB or 4MB depending on bitness, but this space is merely reserved. It's not committed (thus using only virtual address space) until something actually requires that much stack.

As far as I know, the basic idea behind why it's uncatchable is that by then you've run out of *all* the stack and thus can't really execute anything other than code *very* carefully designed for the out-of-stack condition. But this begs the obvious solution: throw `StackOverflowException` *before* we have run out of *all* the stack space!

Why isn't this done? The only remotely sensible reason I can think of is that it was decided that the extra *virtual address space* that this would consume (not real memory usage, mind you!) is not worth the benefit of making this exception catchable.

Are there other concerns I haven't considered?

I feel I have to ask, because most answers addressing this on SO seem to imply that it's impossible to get this to work reasonably well, and *that* is why .NET makes them uncatchable.

---

The exact implementation details for the catchable variant seem unimportant, but here's just one idea. First, double the default reserved stack size, but set the exception to trigger at 1MB usage. So far this is exactly the same as the existing approach. But when the threshold is reached, instead of throwing an uncatchable exception, throw a catchable one while increasing the threshold to 1.5MB. If the exception is caught and we blow through the limit again, set it to 1.75MB. Then 1.875MB. Etc. Each nested and handled exception gets an ever decreasing amount of extra stack space to get handled until we get close enough to 2MB to require an uncatchable variant to be thrown.

To decrease the threshold back after a successful handling of the StackOverflowException, let's mark the memory page at half the stack size that we just blew through (so 0.5MB in the first instance) to fault on write. The fault handler will be triggered pretty much exclusively when we're back down to that level of stack usage, so it's not expensive. The handler will check the actual stack size and drop the threshold back if appropriate.

Comment: I hope for your sake Eric isn't on holiday today and can provide an answer to this one.

Comment: A managed thread commits its entire stack space.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen It does? Do you have an authoritative reference, since that seems rather wasteful?

Comment: See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2009/09/16/a-thread-s-stack.aspx

Comment: Better link: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,4c0e068c-f7d7-4979-86b1-688b5a29c115.aspx

Comment: @BrianRasmussen That might well be why then. All that committed stack space would end up unusable _except_ for handling `StackOverflowException`s. Although to be fair that space is only wasted in the page file until used, so still not a huge cost... Thanks for the great-looking links; reading through them. ([another link about committing the whole stack](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/03/10/TheCLRCommitsTheWholeStack.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why it was changed from 1.1 to 2.0 (hopefully Eric is around to comment sometime), but I suspect because of situations like this:

```
public bool Count(int64 i)
{
    try
    {
        // somewhere in here a stack overflow exception is thrown
        if(i < int64.MaxValue)
            return Count(i+1);
        else
            return true;
    } Catch(StackOverflowException soEx)
    {
        HandleError(soEx);
    }
}

public void HandleError(Exception ex)
{
    // error handling code here
}
```

You would actually throw an exception in your `HandleError(soEx);` line as well because it stopped just before the stack was too full.

I suspect this is the reason why they chose to make stack overflow exception uncatchable, because you can't catch it and then call any method in that catch block.

As for your suggestion, they didn't want to have a stack size and an effective stack size as that then complicates things, I would suspect they also wouldn't want to have a variable stack size. Either of these things would over complicate the framework and only provide a partial solution, for arguement's sake what if you code was:

```
public void HandleError(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        HandleError(soEx);
    } Catch(StackOverflowException soEx)
    {
        HandleError(soEx);
    }
}
```

With a variable stack and no way to actually prevent the StackOverflowException from being caught this would crash something else.

So it's easier and much more predictable to have it just throw and be un-catchable.

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599238/288747) points out the only cases where you *can* still catch StackOverflowExceptions in CLR 2.0+

Comment: I got tired of the downvotes, good luck supporting this question ;)

Comment: @HansPassant As you said, the overall reason is just because there is no way of ensuring that there won't be a `StackOverflowException` thrown within the catch block itself which would then mask the original exception. This is also the basis of the reason why you shouldn't throw exceptions in your `Dispose()` methods, because it masks any previous error and makes the behavour unpredictable (which is one of the major things they reworked with .NET 2.0 in general).