# Is it possible for an exception to bubble up if catching the general Exception?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Let's say we have C# called by an unmanaged C++ application.  The caller's code is unavailable.

```
public void MethodCalledByUnmanagedCode()
{
try
{
   DoWork()
}
catch {}//assume we swallow exception, no logging or anything
}
```

In this case, is there any way possible for any exception to bubble up to unmanaged C++ in any circumstance?

Comment: @pst - there are reports of exceptions bubbling up in exactly this circumstance.  I want to know how that is possible.  Note that there is a logging mechanism that will be plugged in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code could raise a [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx).

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.

Comment: +1. Note that with some effort automatice re-throw could be prevented.

Answer (score 2):

There are also exceptions that will never make to your exception handler like StackOverflowException in normal circumstances.

See details [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception).