# Debugging unit tests that fail due to a StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, stack-overflow

Whenever a unit test fails due to a `StackOverflowException` the unit test process immediately exits - the only way to find out what happened (that I am aware of) is to debug a crash dump of the unit test process obtained by following the steps found here

- [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx)

What is the easiest way of getting the name of the unit test that was running at the time that the `StackOverflowException` was thrown? Even when debugging the unit test I'm struggling to find the name of the current unit test as its at the bottom of the stack and Visual Studio wont' shown the entire stack in the debugging window because its too large.

Is there some way to find out which unit test failed without collecting and debugging crash dumps?

Comment: I'm not sure what is truncating the exception. Could you try making your own stacktrace with `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true)` in the watch and/or intermediate window? Maybe this will provide you a full trace.

Comment: @Caramiriel Running that while debugging interactively gives `Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.`, you can't run immediate expressions when debugging a crash dump as the process is not actually running at that point.  The whole stack trace is not shown because its massive.

Comment: @Justin: If your visual studio architecture (eg. x86) matches your application's, then you can also load SOS and dump the stacktrace by typing `!clrstack` in the immediate window. Seems to be working for me. (`0028ed6c 00340147 ConsoleApplication45.Program.Rec() 0028edac 003400fb ConsoleApplication45.Program.Main(System.String[])`)

Comment: What is your unit test process/harness/tool? You should be getting a log of the progress (perhaps a console output?), so even if the harness is not able to gracefully handle `StackOverflowException`, you should be able to see in the log the name of the test method that was running last.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack.aspx). You might want to call it in your recursive method(s) to get `InsufficientExecutionStackException` ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception), you can't really catch a stack overflow exception unless you throw it yourself.

So, as a workaround to your problem (not really a solution) you can insert a method call in you code to detect a stack overflow, then throw the exception manually and catch it later.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestStackOverflowDetection
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDetectStackOverflow()
    {
        try
        {
            InfiniteRecursion();
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private static int InfiniteRecursion(int i = 0)
    {
        // Insert the following call in all methods that
        // we suspect could be part of an infinite recursion 
        CheckForStackOverflow(); 

        // Force an infinite recursion
        var j = InfiniteRecursion(i) + 1;
        return j;
    }

    private static void CheckForStackOverflow()
    {
        var stack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
        if (stack.FrameCount > 1000) // Set stack limit to 1,000 calls
        {
            // Output last 10 frames in the stack
            foreach (var f in stack.GetFrames().Reverse().Take(30).Reverse())
                Debug.Write("\tat " + f);

            // Throw a stack overflow exception
            throw new StackOverflowException();
        }
    }
```