# Why does this terminate my app without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the YAX Serializer (current NuGet version).  When I run this code:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        int zero = 0;
        int result = 100 / zero;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {
        LogSaveException(ex);
    }
}

public void LogSaveException(object value)
{
    try
    {
        YAXSerializer serializer = new YAXSerializer(value.GetType());
        string loggedString = serializer.Serialize(value);
        Console.WriteLine(loggedString);
    }
    catch (StackOverflowException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log Error", "Could Not Log object of type " 
                  + value.GetType().ToString() +" due to stack overflow.");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log Error", "Could Not Log object of type " 
                + value.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

The app ends on this line: `string loggedString = serializer.Serialize(value);`

I have tried to catch any exception that I can see would happen.  But the app just ends.

I tried running it in LinqPad and it crashed LinqPad.  I tried to debug the crash of LinqPad (even though I do not have the source, sometimes you can get some info from it.)  When I did that it said that there was a StackOverflowException.  But my catch statement did not catch it.

**What would cause a total death like that?  How how do I guard against it?**

Comment: Simple. Beware of recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stackoverflow exceptions have limited "catchability" in CLR > 2.0.  See the blog post below for more details; the behavior you're experiencing is exactly what's described.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception.aspx

While annoying, this does make sense: if you've blown your stack, what would a consistent/safe/sane recovery look like?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a serious error with the `YAXSerializer`.

`StackOverflowException` cannot be caught (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception) amongst others for reference) because there's rarely any recovery from such a serious error.

**EDIT:** or it's an error with the class you're serializing.  Do you have a cyclic reference in the object you're passing in?