# C# stack overflow is not able to be handled

Tags: c#, error-handling

When I call this method in a try catch, stackoverflow is not able to be handled.

```
public int Calculate()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Calculate();
    }
}

public void Call()
{
    try
    {
        Calculate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);          
    }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: How do you manage your exit condition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception