# JSON.NET StackOverflowException while serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, stack-overflow

My C# program is running into StackOverflowException, when I try to serialize object with similar structure like this:

- Object has members which reference each other
- can't be try catched (idk why)
- if count is set below 6500 (may vary depending on machine) it is successfully serialized

Example code below:

```
class Chacha
{
    public Chacha NextChacha { get; set; }
}    
public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int count = 15000;

        Chacha[] steps = new Chacha[count];
        steps[0] = new Chacha();

        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            steps[i] = new Chacha();
            steps[i-1].NextChacha = steps[i];
        }

        string serSteps = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(steps, Settings);
}
```

JSON.NET version is: 9.0.1 
.NET Framework: 4.5.2  
Any solutions how to serialize this structure?
Any help or suggestion is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *"Object has members which reference each other"* ← there's your problem. Is it a tree-structure or can it contain loops and self-references? (your actual code, not the example)

Comment: *"can't be try catched (idk why)"* [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception)

Comment: `for (int count = 10000; count < 100000; count++)` - how many times do you expect that loop to execute?

Comment: `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` always serializes the *first* occurrence of each object - and the first occurrence of all the objects occurs at index 0 of your `steps` array.  I.e. you're trying to serialize a linked list of 90,000 items as nested JSON objects 90,000 levels deep.  Of course you're going to get a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet let's asume if will run just once with count = 15 000

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer it's Linked-list structure. Can't post actual code or project, but this example describe (create) same issue.

Comment: @dbc Yes, it tries exactly that and I'm looking for solution in this situation

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks. Helped

Comment: @Tatranskymedved edited. I'm looking for way how to serialize similiar structure (linked list)

Comment: Right, so you'll end up with JSON that would be 15,000 levels deep. It sounds unlikely that that's ever going to work...

Comment: @JonSkeet Are you familiar with any solution for this kind of situations? Thanks for replays

Comment: Well first you need to think what you actually want the JSON to look like. I strongly suspect you *don't* want hugely nested JSON...

Comment: Write code that can convert your list to and from an `IEnumerable`, then serialize that. It is possible to do this with no more than constant overhead by serializing as an array, regardless of how large the linked list is. Whether you can get JSON.NET to do that without custom serialization is another matter. Better yet, just use `LinkedList` instead of rolling your own. Better yet, use `List`, since linked lists are rarely an efficient solution outside of homework exercises due to their locality issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you are getting the stackoverflow exception is that Json.NET is a recursive, single-pass tree or graph serializer that, when [`PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) is enabled, always serializes the *first* occurrence of each object.  You have constructed your 15,000 element `Chacha []` array so that the first entry is the head of a linked list containing all the other items linked sequentially.  Json.NET will try to serialize that to nested JSON objects 15,000 levels deep via 15,000 levels of recursion, overflowing the stack in the process.

Thus what you need to do is write the entire table of linkages only at the *head* of the list, as a JSON array.  Unfortunately, however, Json.NET is also a contract-based serializer which means it will try to write the same properties whenever it encounters an object of a given type, no matter what the nesting depth is.  Thus adding a `Chacha[] NextChachaList` property to your `Chacha` object doesn't help since it will get written at each level.  Instead it will be necessary to create a fairly complex [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that tracks the serialization depth in a thread-safe manner and only writes the linkage list only at the top level.  The following does the trick:

```
class ChachaConverter : LinkedListItemConverter<Chacha>
{
    protected override bool IsNextItemProperty(JsonProperty member)
    {
        return member.UnderlyingName == "NextChacha"; // Use nameof(Chacha.NextChacha) in latest c#
    }
}

public abstract class LinkedListItemConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
    const string refProperty = "$ref";
    const string idProperty = "$id";
    const string NextItemListProperty = "nextItemList";

    [ThreadStatic]
    static int level;

    // Increments the nesting level in a thread-safe manner.
    int Level { get { return level; } set { level = value; } }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    protected abstract bool IsNextItemProperty(JsonProperty member);

    List<T> GetNextItemList(object value, JsonObjectContract contract)
    {
        var property = contract.Properties.Where(p => IsNextItemProperty(p)).Single();
        List<T> list = null;
        for (var item = (T)property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value); item != null; item = (T)property.ValueProvider.GetValue(item))
        {
            if (list == null)
                list = new List<T>();
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

    void SetNextItemLinks(object value, List<T> list, JsonObjectContract contract)
    {
        var property = contract.Properties.Where(p => IsNextItemProperty(p)).Single();
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            return;
        var previous = value;
        foreach (var next in list)
        {
            if (next == null)
                continue;
            property.ValueProvider.SetValue(previous, next);
            previous = next;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (new PushValue<int>(Level + 1, () => Level, (old) => Level = old))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            if (serializer.ReferenceResolver.IsReferenced(serializer, value))
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(refProperty);
                writer.WriteValue(serializer.ReferenceResolver.GetReference(serializer, value));
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(idProperty);
                writer.WriteValue(serializer.ReferenceResolver.GetReference(serializer, value));

                var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());

                // Write the data properties (if any).
                foreach (var property in contract.Properties
                    .Where(p => p.Readable && !p.Ignored && (p.ShouldSerialize == null || p.ShouldSerialize(value))))
                {
                    if (IsNextItemProperty(property))
                        continue;
                    var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
                    if (propertyValue == null && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
                        continue;
                    writer.WritePropertyName(property.PropertyName);
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
                }

                if (Level == 1)
                {
                    // Write the NextItemList ONLY AT THE TOP LEVEL
                    var nextItems = GetNextItemList(value, contract);
                    if (nextItems != null)
                    {
                        writer.WritePropertyName(NextItemListProperty);
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, nextItems);
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Detach and process $ref
        var refValue = (string)jObject[refProperty].RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
        if (refValue != null)
        {
            var reference = serializer.ReferenceResolver.ResolveReference(serializer, refValue);
            if (reference != null)
                return reference;
        }

        // Construct the value
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(existingValue == null ? typeof(T) : existingValue.GetType());
        T value = (existingValue as T ?? (T)contract.DefaultCreator());

        // Detach and process $id
        var idValue = (string)jObject[idProperty].RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
        if (idValue != null)
        {
            serializer.ReferenceResolver.AddReference(serializer, idValue, value);
        }

        // Detach the (possibly large) list of next items.
        var nextItemList = jObject[NextItemListProperty].RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();

        // populate the data properties (if any)
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), value);

        // Set the next item references
        if (nextItemList != null)
        {
            var list = nextItemList.ToObject<List<T>>(serializer);
            SetNextItemLinks(value, list, contract);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            setValue(oldValue);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JContainer && t.Parent.Type != JTokenType.Property).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contained != null)
            contained.Remove();
        // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
        if (node.Parent is JProperty)
            ((JProperty)node.Parent).Value = null;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Then, given the slightly modified class `Chacha`:

```
class Chacha
{
    public Chacha NextChacha { get; set; }

    public long Data { get; set; }
}
```

The following JSON is generated for an array of 3 items:

```
{
  "$type": "Question41828014.Chacha[], Tile",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "1",
      "Data": 0,
      "nextItemList": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Question41828014.Chacha, Tile]], mscorlib",
        "$values": [
          {
            "$id": "2",
            "Data": 1
          },
          {
            "$id": "3",
            "Data": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "2"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the JSON depth is now strictly limited.  Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GJHuCS).

Be aware that, once you specify a custom converter for your type, it needs to do everything manually.  If your type `Chacha` is polymorphic and you need to read and write `"$type"` properties, you will need to add that logic to the converter yourself.

By the way, I recommend `TypeNameHandling.Objects` instead of `TypeNameHandling.All`.  Object types may reasonably be specified in the JSON (as long as the types are properly [sanitized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json)) but collection types should be specified in the code.  Doing so makes it possible to switch from an array to a `List<T>` without having to postread legacy JSON files.

Comment: thank you. Base on your idea we created our own serializer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Model
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
 }
List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
list.Add(new Model { Id = 1, Name = "Jon", SurName = "Snow"});
var stringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC with Jquery:

install newtonsoft package through console nuget package:
install-package Newtonsoft.json -Version 6.0.1

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Get_Country()
    {
        string _data = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_Country", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        return Json(_data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(string A,string B,string C,string D)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Employee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", A);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", B);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", C);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobbies", D);
        int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Get_Employees()
    {
        string _data = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_Employees", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        return Json(_data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditData(int A)
    {
        string _data = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_Employees_Edit", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", A);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        return Json(_data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View :

Scripting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var IDD = "";
            
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Get_Country();
        GetEmployees();
    });

    function Get_Country() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee/Get_Country',
            type: 'post',
            data: {},
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt);
                for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                    $('#ddlCountry').append($('<option/>').attr('value',_dt[i].CID).text(_dt[i].CName));
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error in Country Bind');
            }
        })
    }

    function SaveData() {
        debugger    
        var HOB = "";
        if ($("#btnsave").val() == ("Save")) {
            HOB = $('input:checkbox:checked.B').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee/Insert',
                type: 'post',
                data: { A: $('#txtName').val(), B: $('#ddlCountry').val(), C: $('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val(), D: HOB },
                success: function () {
                    alert('data saved');
                    GetEmployees();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('saved error');
                }
            });
        }
    }


    function GetEmployees() {
        debugger
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee/Get_Employees',
            type: 'post',
            data: {},
            async: false,
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt);
                $('#tbl').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                    $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + _dt[i].ID + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].Name + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].CName + '</td><td>' + (_dt[i].Gender == 1 ? 'Male' : _dt[i].Gender == 2 ? 'Female' : 'Others') + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].Hobbies + '</td><td><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="EditData(' + _dt[i].ID + ')"/></td><td><input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteData(' + _dt[i].ID + ')"/></td></tr>')
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error in binding');
            }
        });
    }
    


    function EditData(id) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee/EditData',
            type: 'post',
            data: { A: id },
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt);
                debugger;
                $("#txtName").val(_dt[0].Name);
                $("#ddlCountry").val(_dt[0].CID);
                $("input[name=A][value=" + _dt[0].Gender + "]").prop('checked', true);

                var hbb = _dt[0].Hobbies;
                var arr = hbb.split(',');
                $('input:checkbox:checked.B').prop('checked', false);
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    $('input:checkbox[class=B][value=' + arr[i] + ']').prop('checked', true);
                }

                $("#btnsave").val("Update");
                IDD = id;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('edit error !!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Body :

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtName" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCountry">
                    <option value="0"><--Select--></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="1" />Male
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="2" />Female
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="3" />Others
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hobbies :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Cricket" />Cricket
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Coding" />Coding
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Travelling" />Travelling
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Swimming" />Swimming
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Movies" />Movies
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="Typing" />Typing
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="SaveData()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tbl" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Hobbies</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
Jquery cs code:

```csharp
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);

[WebMethod]
public string GetCountry()
{
    string _data = "";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
    return _data;
}

[WebMethod]
public void Insert(string A, int B, int C, string D)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", A);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", B);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", C);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", D);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}


[WebMethod]
public void Delete(int ID)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

[WebMethod]
public string Edit(int ID)
{
    string _data = "";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_edit", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
    return _data;
}

[WebMethod]
public void Update(int ID, string A, int B, int C, string D)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_update", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", A);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", B);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", C);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", D);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

[WebMethod]
public string GetEmployee()
{
    string _data = "";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_get", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
    return _data;
}
```







aspx code:

Scripting :

```html
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var IDD = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CountryBind();
        //EmployeeBind();
    });

    function CountryBind() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'Employee.asmx/GetCountry',
            type:'post',
            contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType:'json',
            data:'{}',
            async: false,
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                    $("#ddlcountry").append($('<option/>').attr("value", _dt[i].cid).text(_dt[i].cname));
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('CountryBind error');
            }
        });
    }


    function SaveData() {
        var HOB = "";
        HOB = $('input:checkbox:checked.B').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(',');
        if ($("#btnsave").val()==("Save")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee.asmx/Insert',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{A:'" + $("#txtname").val() + "',B:'" + $("#ddlcountry").val() + "',C:'" + $('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val() + "',D:'" + HOB + "'}",
                success: function () {
                    alert('insert success !!');
                    EmployeeBind();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('insert error !!');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee.asmx/Update',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{ID:" + IDD + ",A:'" + $("#txtname").val() + "',B:'" + $("#ddlcountry").val() + "',C:'" + $('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val() + "',D:'" + HOB + "'}",
                success: function () {
                    alert('Update Successfully');
                    EmployeeBind();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Update error');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function EmployeeBind() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee.asmx/GetEmployee',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{}",
            async: false,
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                $("#tbl").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                    $("#tbl").append('<tr><td>' + _dt[i].name + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].cname + '</td><td>' + (_dt[i].gender == "1" ? "Male" : _dt[i].gender == "2" ? "FeMale" : "Others") + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].hobbies + '</td><td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" onclick="EditData(' + _dt[i].id + ')" /><td><input type="button" id="btndelete" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteData(' + _dt[i].id + ')" /></td</tr>');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('EmployeeBind error');
            }
        });
    }

    function DeleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee.asmx/Delete',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{ID:'" + id + "'}",
            success: function () {
                alert('Delete Successfully');
                EmployeeBind();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('DeleteData error');
            }
        });
    }

    function EditData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Employee.asmx/Edit',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async:false,
            data: "{ID:'" + id + "'}",
            success: function (_dt) {
                _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                $("#txtname").val(_dt[0].name);
                $("#ddlcountry").val(_dt[0].cid);
                $("input[name=A][value=" + _dt[0].gender + "]").prop('checked', true);

                var hbb = _dt[0].hobbies;
                var arr = hbb.split(',');
                $("input:checkbox:checked.B").prop('checked', false);
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    $("input:checkbox[class=B][value=" + arr[i] + ']').prop('checked', true);
                }

                $("#btnsave").val("Update");
                IDD = id;
                EmployeeBind();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('EditData error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Body:

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td><select id="ddlcountry">
                    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="1" /> male
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="2" /> female
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="3" /> other
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hobbies :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="cricket" /> cricket
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="music" /> music
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="movies" /> movies
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="cooking" /> cooking
                <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="coding" /> coding
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="SaveData()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table id="tbl" border="1" style="border-color:darkblue;width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Hobbies</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```
````

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but explain how and why your code solves the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Asp.net Outside Gridview:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Asp_outside_gridview.Employee" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validation() {
            var errors = "";
            errors += checkname();
            errors += dob();
            errors += email();
            errors += password();
            errors += cpassword();
            errors += mobile();
            errors += salary();
            errors += country();
            errors += state();
            errors += city();
            if (errors != "") {
                alert(errors);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function checkname() {
            var TBN=document.getElementById('txtname');
            var exp = "/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/";
            if (TBN.value="") {
                return 'please enter your NAME!\n'
            }
            else if (exp.test(TBN.value)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'plese enter only alphabets in NAME!\n';
            }
        }
        function dob() {
            var TBdob = document.getElementById('txtdob');
            if (TBdob.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your DATE OF BIRTH!\n'
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }
        function email() {
            var TBemail = document.getElementById('txtemail');
            var exp = "/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/";
            if (TBemail.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your EMAIL ID!\n'
            }
            else if (exp.test(TBemail.value)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'plese enter valid email id!\n';
            }
        }
        function password() {
            var TBpassword = document.getElementById('txtpassword');
            var exp = "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,10}$/";
            if (TBpassword.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your PASSWORD!\n'
            }
            else if (exp.test(TBpassword.value)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'password should be of Minimum eight and maximum 10 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character!\n';
            }
        }
        function cpassword() {
            var TBpassword = document.getElementById('txtpassword');
            var TBcpassword = document.getElementById('txtcpassword');
            if (TBcpassword.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your CONFIRM PASSWORD!\n'
            }
            else if (TBpassword.value== TBcpassword.value) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'password do not match!\n';
            }
        }
        function mobile() {
            var TBmobile = document.getElementById('txtmobile');
            var exp = /^\d{10}$/;
            if (TBmobile.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your MOBILE NUMBER!\n'
            }
            else if (exp.test(TBmobile.value)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'plese enter only valid MOBILE NUMBER!\n';
            }
        }
        function salary() {
            var TBsalary = document.getElementById('txtsalary');
            var exp = /^\d{10}$/;
            if (TBsalary.value = "") {
                return 'please enter your SALARY!\n'
            }
            else if (exp.test(TBsalary.value)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                'plese enter only numbers in SALARY!\n';
            }
        }
        function country() {
            var TBcountry = document.getElementById('ddlcountry');
            if (TBcountry.value = "0") {
                return 'please Select your Country!\n'
            }
            else  {
                return "";
            }
        }
        function state() {
            var TBstate = document.getElementById('ddlstate');
            if (TBstate.value = "0") {
                return 'please Select your State!\n'
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }
        function city() {
            var TBcity = document.getElementById('ddlcity');
            if (TBcity.value = "0") {
                return 'please Select your City!\n'
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }        
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ajaxcal" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country :</td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State :</td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="caldob" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txtdob" TargetControlID="txtdob" PopupPosition="Right"></ajax:CalendarExtender></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblgender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Others" Value="3" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image :</td>
                <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fuimage" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hobbies :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkhobbies" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cricket"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Football" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Coding" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Reading" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Travelling" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Gym" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Singing" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Dancing" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Music" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Movies" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cooking" ></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IsActive :</td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkisactive" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnsave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnsave_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand">
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("id") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("name") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="country">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("cname") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="state">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("sname") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("dob") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("gender").ToString() == "1" ? "Male" : Eval("gender").ToString() == "2" ? "Female" :"Others" %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="40px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image","~/Employee/{0}") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <%#Eval("hobbies") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("isactive").ToString() == "1" ? "Active" : "Inactive" %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtndelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="DLT" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="EDT" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Fill_Country();
            ddlstate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            Fill_Grid();
        }
    }

    public void Fill_Country()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "cid";
            ddlcountry.DataTextField = "cname";
            ddlcountry.DataSource = ds;
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
            ddlcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
    }

    public void Fill_State(string cid)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_state_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid";
            ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
            ddlstate.DataSource = ds;
            ddlstate.DataBind();
            ddlstate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
    }

    public void Fill_Grid()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grd.DataSource = ds;
            grd.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grd.DataSource = null;
            grd.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fill_State(ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnsave.Text == "Save")
        {
            string HOB = "";
            string FN = "";
            string Ext = "";
            Ext = Path.GetExtension(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (Ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".png")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chkhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (chkhobbies.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        HOB += chkhobbies.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
                FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
                fuimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + FN));
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", ddlstate.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", FN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", HOB);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isactive", chkisactive.Checked == true ? 1 : 0);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "please upload only image file !!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string HOB = "";
            string FN = "";
            string Ext = "";
            Ext = Path.GetExtension(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (Ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".png")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chkhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (chkhobbies.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        HOB += chkhobbies.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
                FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
                fuimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + FN));
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + ViewState["IMG"]));                    
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_update", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ViewState["ID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", ddlstate.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", FN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", HOB);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isactive", chkisactive.Checked == true ? 1 : 0);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "please upload only image file !!";
            }
        }
        Fill_Grid();
    }

    protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName=="EDT")
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_edit", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.CommandArgument);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                ddlcountry.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cid"].ToString();
                Fill_State(ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                ddlstate.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sid"].ToString();
                txtdob.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dob"].ToString();
                rblgender.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gender"].ToString() == "1" ? "1" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["gender"].ToString() == "2" ? "2" : "3";
                chkisactive.Checked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["isactive"].ToString() == "1" ? true : false;
                string[] arr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hobbies"].ToString().Split(',');
                chkhobbies.ClearSelection();
                for (int i = 0; i < chkhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (chkhobbies.Items[i].Text == arr[j])
                        {
                            chkhobbies.Items[i].Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ViewState["IMG"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
                btnsave.Text = "Update";
                ViewState["ID"] = e.CommandArgument;
            }
        }
        else if(e.CommandName == "DLT")
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.CommandArgument);
            SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            string Old_image = cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value.ToString();
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + Old_image));
            Fill_Grid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Help us out, please. This is just a giant dump of code on a question that was already answered four years ago. What is this? What is the relevant part? Why is it preferable over the existing answers?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
    Asp.net Inside Gridview:
    
    aspx:
    
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Asp_inside_gridview.Employee" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ajaxcal" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country :</td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="caldob" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txtdob" TargetControlID="txtdob" PopupPosition="BottomRight"></ajax:CalendarExtender></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblgender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"/>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Others" Value="3" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image :</td>
                <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fuimage" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hobbies :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkhobbies" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cricket"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Football" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Coding" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Reading" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Travelling" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Gym" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Singing" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Dancing" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Music" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Movies" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cooking" ></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IsActive :</td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkisactive" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnsave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnsave_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowUpdating="grd_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="grd_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="grd_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="grd_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound" >
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("id") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("name") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="country">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("cname") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddleditcountry" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("dob") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txteditdob" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("dob") %>' />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="caleditdob" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txteditdob" TargetControlID="txteditdob" PopupPosition="BottomRight"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("gender").ToString() == "1" ? "Male" : Eval("gender").ToString() == "2" ? "Female" :"Others" %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbleditgender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"/>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Others" Value="3" />
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="80px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image","~/Employee/{0}") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fueditimages" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <%#Eval("hobbies") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkedithobbies" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Cricket"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Football" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Coding" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Reading" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Travelling" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Gym" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Singing" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Dancing" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Music" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Movies" ></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Cooking" ></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("isactive").ToString() == "1" ? "Active" : "Inactive" %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate> 
                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkeditisactive" runat="server" />
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtndelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>                                
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
Fill_Country();
Fill_Grid();
}
}

```
    public void Fill_Country()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "cid";
            ddlcountry.DataTextField = "cname";
            ddlcountry.DataSource = ds;
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
            ddlcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
    }

    public void Fill_Grid()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grd.DataSource = ds;
            grd.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grd.DataSource = null;
            grd.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HOB = "";
        string FN = "";
        string Ext = "";
        Ext = Path.GetExtension(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (Ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Ext.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chkhobbies.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chkhobbies.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    HOB += chkhobbies.Items[i].Text + ",";
                }
            }
            HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');
            FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(fuimage.PostedFile.FileName);
            fuimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + FN));
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rblgender.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", FN);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", HOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isactive", chkisactive.Checked == true ? 1 : 0);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "please upload only image file !!";
        }

        Fill_Grid();
    }

    protected void grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grd.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Fill_Grid();
    }

    protected void grd_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grd.EditIndex = -1;
        Fill_Grid();
    }

    protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string IDD = grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", IDD);
        SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        string PPP = cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value.ToString();
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + PPP));
        Fill_Grid();
    }

    protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddleditcountry");
                CheckBoxList CBL = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("chkedithobbies");
                RadioButtonList RBL = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbleditgender");
                CheckBox CBIA = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkeditisactive");

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDL.DataValueField = "cid";
                    DDL.DataTextField = "cname";
                    DDL.DataSource = ds;
                    DDL.DataBind();
                    DDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                }

                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                DDL.SelectedValue = drv["cid"].ToString();
                RBL.SelectedValue = drv["gender"].ToString();
                string[] arr = drv["hobbies"].ToString().Split(',');
                CBL.ClearSelection();
                for (int i = 0; i < CBL.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (CBL.Items[i].Text == arr[j])
                        {
                            CBL.Items[i].Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                CBIA.Checked = drv["isactive"].ToString() == "1" ? true : false;
                ViewState["IMG"] = drv["image"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TBN = (TextBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txteditname");
        DropDownList DDLC = (DropDownList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddleditcountry");
        TextBox TBD = (TextBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txteditdob");
        RadioButtonList RBLG = (RadioButtonList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("rbleditgender");
        FileUpload FUI = (FileUpload)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("fueditimages");
        CheckBoxList CBLH = (CheckBoxList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkedithobbies");
        CheckBox CBI = (CheckBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkeditisactive");
        string IDD = grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string FN = "";
        string HOB = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < CBLH.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CBLH.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                HOB += CBLH.Items[i].Text + ",";
            }
        }
        HOB = HOB.TrimEnd(',');

        FN = Path.GetFileName(FUI.PostedFile.FileName);

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_update", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", IDD);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TBN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", DDLC.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TBD.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RBLG.SelectedValue);
        if (FN != "")
        {
            FN = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + FN;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", FN);
            FUI.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + FN));
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Employee" + "\\" + ViewState["IMG"]));

        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", ViewState["IMG"]);
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", HOB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isactive", CBI.Checked == true ? "1" : "2");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        grd.EditIndex = -1;
        Fill_Grid();
    }
```