# Stackoverflow.. literally.. on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am seeking some advice on how to instrument for stack overflow and other critical errors in ASP.NET azure.

I recently introduced a "minor" defect with a function that looks like this:

```
public void foo()
{ 
    return foo();
}
```

What was surprising was there was no way to catch this error in the Azure environment.  Its running as a "WebApp" (asp.net), and I have global error handlers, and the call was wrapped in an try/catch block. All logging turned on in Azure.  Nothing in Azure web or app log stream - basically just getting a 503.

Note: this is NOT a duplicate of a seven year old question.  This is specific to latest (4.6+) .NET Framework running in an azure environment.

Comment: Catching an SO is always a bit different than other errors and most possibly cannot be caught, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception

Comment: Is it causing a crash?  It is possible that this code could be optimized to tail call recursion which would cause an infinite loop and not a stack overflow.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of a seven year old question..  frameworks have changed, hosting environment is totally different.

Comment: @Mike I believe so, specifically getting a 503 and recycling.  Stack overflow locally as well.  Outside chance Azure is recycling because of infinite loop, but brings us back to original question - where's the logs?