# Application (VB.Net) gets crashed due to Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll. after try calling TcpClient.Connect(IP) API for 1000 times

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I face this issue for a while and don't have a good idea how to resolve it.

The application is actually a DLL coded in VB.NET 2013 compiled with .NET framework 4.6.1 in used to do message exchange via TCP port.

The DLL is loaded and running in Win2012R2 with .NET framework 4.5 . DLL is running well without issue when TCP port is connecting.

However, the DLL gets crashed after retrying to open TCP port for a while (in the log file I logged, the retry count reached 1000+ times).

I try to look for the root cause and I found the `clr.dll` is the main reason causing crash. In other articles I found some information but seems not quite similar to mine...

Below is the windows event log for your reference. 
I wonder if anyone has faced this issue and resolved it please kind let me know.

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        Application Error
>   Date:          4/5/2018 2:23:48 AM
>   Event ID:      1000
>   Task Category: (100)
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      Server11
>   Description:
>   Faulting application name: MyProgram.exe, version: 7.8.0.30, time stamp: 0x5984af0d
>   Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2053.0, time stamp: 0x58fa6bb3
>   Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>   Fault offset: 0x0045138d
>   Faulting process id: 0x1e04
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d3cc2fb84774be
>   Faulting application path: MyProgram.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Report Id: ef43e05d-382c-11e8-80bf-000c291e7679
>   Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: This would just be killing the symptom, but would you consider giving up after x failed retries? In which timeframe are you trying to open these 1000 connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, the exception code `0xc00000fd` is a *StackOverflow Exception*.

This maybe because of recursion or many other issues. however my money is on recursion.

Since its likely a *StackOverflow Expception* i think you will need to debug the process to catch it properly.

> Starting with 2.0 a StackOverflow Exception can only be caught in the
>   following circumstances.
>
> - The CLR is being run in a hosted environment where the host specifically allows for StackOverflow exceptions to be handled
> - The stackoverflow exception is thrown by user code and not due to an actual stack overflow situation (Reference)

Source [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception)

This is also worth reading [When can you catch a StackOverflowException?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception/)

In short, i doubt this is a bug with .net its self and most likely due to what you are doing (or someone else), since you haven't shown the code all we can assume is you/they are doing something wrong.

Some good practices are

- Don't use recursion to do any thing silly when connection fails.
- Make sure you are always disposing and cleaning up your `TcpClient` or using a `using` statement
- If you are trying to do things simultaneously with `TcpClient`, make sure you are not using `Parallel.For/ForEach` or anything that is not suitable for *IO Bound* operations, instead use the `async`/`await` pattern (although this is probably not the problem, its good advice).
- Don't blindly use other peoples libraries

Good luck

Comment: Hi, Sir! 
Thanks for the tip! I did find the reason. it is caused by another dll imported running in another thread for status monitoring is doing recursion in exception handling.

Thanks again for the valued tips!

Comment: @JimYu hi, im glad your sorted it out, if it helped you out don't forget to up vote and mark it as thr accepted answer