# How to handle StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

I got a huge `IEnumerable` and when i try to convert it in `Array`:

```
var arr = myEnumerable.ToArray();
```

I got an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll
```

Same error fired when i do another operations with this collection for example:

```
var count = myEnumerable.Count();
```

In `Visual Studio` i tried to see this collections's properties but when i put mouse coursor on it debug mode end end to work.

I fix this and remove `IEnumerable` and work with `Array` only.
But what i don't understand. My code covered by `try catch` but i can not handle this exception.
In meny [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception) i read that i can't handle `StackOverflowException` what fired in non user code.

Does it mean that all can do it is just fix error and  do not try to catch `StackOverflowException`?

Comment: You can't handle that truth.  SOE can be raised at any code, it is not necessarily (or likely) that it is the ToArray() call that caused it.  Find the recursion bug in your code by single-stepping it with the debugger, paying attention to the call stack.

Comment: What exactly is your `IEnumerable`? Is it just a `List<T>`? Or is it a custom class, and did you write the enumerator?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1599219/3744182).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't - a `StackOverflowException` is a fatal error, basically. You can't catch it; you need to fix your code.

Even if you *could* catch `StackOverflowException`, it would still indicate a bug that should be fixed, a bit like `NullReferenceException` does.

You should look at how your sequence is evaluated. You might get this error if you have a naive tree-walking algorithm using `yield return` with a recursive call, and a deep tree, for example.

A `StackOverflowException` almost always involves recursion, and the fix almost always involves either removing recursion entirely, or drastically reducing how much recursion is required.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/