# How to determine code location for stack overflow exception using DebugDiag or WinDbg?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

On occasion, we get some Stack Overflow exceptions with our C#/ASP.NET 4.5 web application running under IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). Last week, it just so happens that we had 5 stack overflow exceptions occur within a 2-minute period causing the app pool to be disabled. This has happened a couple of other times over the last 6 months.

I am trying to track down which part(s) of my code would be causing this to happen.  I ran WinDbg and DebugDiag with the crash dump file (within c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\wer\ folder) but am unable to determine what in my code is causing these exceptions due to the fact that I do not really know what it is that I am looking at to determine the culprit(s).

Any guidance on how to read the analyzed crash dump would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599451/1797425) may be of help.

Comment: In Windbg, after loading the crash dump and SOS (`.loadby sos clr`), list the threads with `!threads`. There should be one with an exception (indicated in the last column). From there, you can switch to the thread and use `!clrstack` to display the callstack

Comment: Here is what I get when I do the first part:

This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(14c8.1334): Stack overflow - code c00000fd (first/second chance not available)

The user dump currently examined is a minidump. Consequently, only a subset
of sos.dll functionality will be available. If needed, attaching to the live
process or debugging a full dump will allow access to sos.dll's full feature
set.
To create a full user dump use the command: .dump /ma <filename>

Comment: Well yes, what about the second part?

Comment: Yes I got it to work, thank you very much.  I realized I needed to load my symbols then I was able to get the rest to work.