# Move to Rebus error queue not triggered after maximum abort failures

Tags: msmq, rebus, poison-queue

The default Rebus configuration, according to the [error handling](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling) wiki, should move a poison message to the error queue. It is not happening in a situation where a third party component is causing a stackoverflow exception. The underlying queue is msmq, so the poison message abort counter is incremented.

Is this behavior because the application exception/exit is causing Rebus to lose its tracking? Either using in-memory counting for failed messages or exit before accounting for the message.

Comment: Answering my own question, yes, the in-memory ErrorTracking is lost.  Rebus does not load external tracking information that is in msmq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the reason Rebus does not track the error in this case, is becase [it's generally not possible to catch `StackOverflowException` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-sharp-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception)(*)

You're out of luck here, sorry.  Tell whoever made that 3rd party component to fix their recursion.

---

(*) It's only possible if the CLR is running with some specific flag set to true AND if the `StackOverflowException` was thrown "manually". If the exception is from the runtime due to an actual stack overflow, then it's impossible to catch.

Comment: Thanks. Already notified 3rd party, waiting ... Two possible solutions in short term, pre-load status from msmq which does persist the counter information because its a separate process or separate execution domain.