# AspNet Core 3.0-3.1 can't catch the unhandled exception (application crashes)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

my goal is to catch all unhandled exceptions. For this purpose, I created Asp.Net Core 3.0 application and added a test method with recursion to the controller

(*it is dummy method was made for test purpose only*)

```cs
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            try
            {
                Test();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

To catch all unhandled exceptions I subscribed to   `currentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;`, and redirected error handling to the error controller

```cs
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/api2/error-local-development");
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/api2/error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
```

I thought it should be enough to handle all exceptions even *stackoverflow* but when I execute the script below the application crashes and I can't intercept this moment.

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" https://localhost:44374/api/test
```

is there a way how to catch this exception and handle it?

Comment: any error message?

Comment: A StackOverflowException cannot be handled as such.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk- here is a message from curl ``` curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" https://localhost:44374/api/test
curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset```

and here is a VS Output dump: 
```
... 
The program '[10192] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
The program '[1068] Ams.Client.Host.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: @user2864740  stackoverflow it one of the rest exceptions and if you tall that I can't catch this exception in the unhandled exception handler - I'd like to ask links where I could read about that?

Comment: Short answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599238/2864740 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception — some of the why’s in https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2018/04/07/handling-stack-overflow-exception-in-c-with-veh/

Comment: A little bit more into SEH-class exceptions, corruption, and why .NET doesn’t handle them: https://www.hexacta.com/advanced-exceptions-in-net/ — such SEH-class exceptions are generally process (or at least appdomain) fatal. A SOE is an even further special case.